# How to Prevent S3/Suspend on F20 when an SSH Connection is Active?

Tags: ssh, connection, sleep

I'd like to prevent an F20 box from entering sleep mode when an active SSH connection is established.

Back in the days of pm-utils this task was simple enough -- all that was necessary was to place a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d, which would return a non-zero exit code if a grep of netstat output detected an established SSH connection.  Unfortunately, this method hasn't worked since F16, when pm-utils was replaced with systemd.  Now, any scripts that are placed in /etc/pm/sleep.d are ignored.

How would this sort of task be accomplished on F20 now that we're in the era of systemd?

Optimally, I'd prefer not to be forced to place every network connection inside of a specially designed wrapper at the time that it is initialized.  That seems overly burdensome.

I'd prefer a method of having the system sleep script poll for the status of active "uninterruptable" network connections prior to executing the suspend to S3, and inhibiting the suspend to S3  if any of a list of specific network connections are active.

TIA.