# How to "kick" an ubuntu over telnet box to prevent suspending

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, suspend

I have a Ubuntu box that I'm playing a game over telnet on my box. The problem is my box goes to sleep on while playing. I have to remember to walk in and move the mouse on occasion to keep it awake.

I don't want to change my suspend function on the box as it works as I like, I'd just like to be able to "kick" it remotely every once in a while to keep it awake. Is there a way to do this?

I found this: [How to Prevent S3/Suspend on F20 when an SSH Connection is Active?](https://superuser.com/questions/838000/how-to-prevent-s3-suspend-on-f20-when-an-ssh-connection-is-active) with no answer.

Comment: I don't have a second desktop on hand to test it, but you could try running `loginctl unlock-session` via SSH. That should unlock the machine and wake the display.

Comment: Make a crontab job (https://www.guru99.com/crontab-in-linux-with-examples.html) to periodically send a char, move moue (https://askubuntu.com/questions/819068/can-we-move-mouse-cursor-by-keyboard-command-in-ubuntu) etc.